# How continue sync with S3CMD after broken connection?

Tags: linux, backup, amazon-s3, upload, s3cmd

I'm using `s3cmd` to backup some logs into `Amazon S3` buckets. Which is a great tool.
But I notice that, very often, my `sync's` are broken, they just cancel and try to upload again, until they can upload the file, but the problem is that they don't continue from where it's stop the upload, the upload starts from the beggening.

There's something that I can do about this ? To continue the upload even if it's broken ?
Change my `.s3cfg` file or add some parameter into my command ?
And what mean `throttle` in `s3cmd` ? I'm asking 'cause when an upload fails, this `throttle` increase.

Comment: what version of s3cmd you are using s3cmd --version?

Comment: s3cmd version 1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Until recently the default timeout was 10 seconds, so unless you have the newest version of the s3cmd, this is probably the case. But this is fixable. Location your .s3cfg file, which should be in your home directory.

Edit the .s3cfg file to add the line:

```
socket_timeout = 300
```

This should fix the issue.